# 非バインド変数のエラーについて

Tags: python

VSCodeにて下記のような記述があるのですが、`"feature" is possibly unbound` との問題がでます。

これはどのようにしたら解決できますか。

```py
def preprocess(self, audio):
        # cutting audio by threshold(しきい値 ｄｂ)
        audio, _ = librosa.effects.trim(audio, self.threshold)

        # すべての音声フェイルを指定した同じサイズに変換
        if self.threshold is not None:
            if len(audio) <= self.sample_length:
                # padding
                pad = self.sample_length - len(audio)
                # .concatenate(a,b) ... bond a(n, m), c to make c(x,y)
                audio = np.concatenate((audio, np.zeros(pad, dtype=np.float32)))
            else:
                # trimming
                start = random.randint(0, len(audio) - self.sample_length - 1)
                audio = audio[start:start + self.sample_length]
            stft = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio))
            mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=self.sample_rate, n_mfcc=40),axis=1)
            chroma = np.mean(librosa.feature.chroma_stft(S=stft, sr=self.sample_rate),axis=1)
            mel = np.mean(librosa.feature.melspectrogram(audio, sr=self.sample_rate),axis=1)
            contrast = np.mean(librosa.feature.spectral_contrast(S=stft, sr=self.sample_rate),axis=1)
            tonnetz = np.mean(librosa.feature.tonnetz(y=librosa.effects.harmonic(audio), sr=self.sample_rate),axis=1)

            feature = np.hstack([mfccs, chroma, mel, contrast, tonnetz])
            feature = np.expand_dims(feature, axis=1)
        
        return feature
```

> "feature" is possibly unbound pylance (report unbound variable)

Comment: `possibly unbound` ということなので `feature = ...` の部分が`if` 文などの中にあるのではないでしょうか。つまり、条件によっては `feature` が定義されない場合があるので、条件分岐よりも以前に適切な値で初期化しておく必要があります（もしくは early return）。

Comment: 調べてみたところ、
```
if n in range(5):
  a = １
else:
  b = 1
print(a)
```
のような場合、unboundになることはわかりました。
今回の場合は、見たところ、条件式の範囲の外にあるように見えます。

Comment: `self.threshold` が `None` の場合に `unbound` になります。

Comment: 見落としていました。
この場合は、if分の前(4行目)あたりに、 feature = np.zero()を追記したら良いということでしょうか。

Comment: `self.threshold` が `None` になる状況の場合に `feature` を `np.zero()` に設定する（戻り値が `np.zero` になる）事が適切なのかどうか？を考慮する必要があるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
もう少し読み込んで考えてみたいと思います。